# How to retrieve tokens from a string that are keywords?

Tags: c, string, pointers, split

For example, if the input is `x+=5`, the program should return an array of `x`, `+=`, `5`. Notice that there is no space between `x` and `+=`, so splitting by spaces only probably won't work, because then you would have to iterate through it all over again to find the keywords.

How would I do something like this?
Is there an efficient way to do this in *C*?

Comment: The most generic advice is to use a lexer. You might want to google that. If you want something lighter weight, you should probably just code it by hand.

Comment: Please post your attempt so far, or provide a minimal working example (MWE) so we can see what you've tried so far, and steer you in the right direction.

Comment: a parser would input the expression, character by character, and apply the rules for identifiers operators, etc to extract the desired array.   Also note, a good parser would take the 'longest' token, so it would not separate '+=' into two tokens.  In general you want to perform some lexical analysis on the expression to extract the tokens.   This kind of activity will quickly escalate into a lot of code, especially if you properly handle all the edge cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) is not specific to C (in the sense that you'll use similar techniques in other programming languages). You could do that with hand-written code (using [finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) coding techniques). You could use a lexer generator like [flex](http://github.com/westes/flex/). You might even use [regexprs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), e.g. [regex.h](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regex.3.html) functions on POSIX systems.

[Parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) is also a well known domain with standard techniques (at least for [context free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language), if you want some efficiency). You could use [recursive descent parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), you could generate a parser using [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) (which has [examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Examples.html) very close to your homework) or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). Read more about [LL parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) & [LR parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser). BTW, parsing techniques can be used for lexing.

BTW, there are tons of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (e.g. interpreters of scripting languages like [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [Lua](http://lua.org), [Python](http://python.org/), etc....), [JSON](http://json.org/), [YAML](http://yaml.org/), XML... parsers, several compilers (e.g. [tinycc](http://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git)) etc... illustrating these techniques. You'll learn a lot by studying their source code.

It could be easier for your to sometimes have a lookahead of one or two characters, e.g. by first reading the entire line (with [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or else [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html), and perhaps even [readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), which gives you a line editor). If you cannot read a whole line consider using [fgetc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) and `ungetc` when needed. The classifying utilities from [`<ctype.h>`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html) like [isalpha](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) might be helpful.

If you care about [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (and in principle you should) things become slightly more complex since some [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters (like €, é, , ...) are represented in UTF-8 by several bytes. A library like [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/) should be very helpful.

Comment: How would I approach this if I want to do it by scratch?

Comment: to code by hand, you would need to code a 'state machine' that has states for every possible case (actually this is not that many states) the hardest part would be coding the state transitions.