# How to create a program to read xlib code

Tags: c++, xlib

Been a little bit rusty in coding but I figured I'd ask this question. I'm trying to create a program that can take a command line filename and scan said file in order to find coordinates of triangles in xlib.  I know that xlib takes triangles in the format T(28,100) (23,35) (99,54) from a file a friend gave me, but after looking and trying out different expression in scanf, I can't seem to grab the coordinates in a way that I can use for an algorithm:

```
 int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    // First need to scan the file.
    char *pFilename = argv[1];
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen(pFilename,"r");
    // char Trig = scanf( ,);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Do you have example data? Also: you probably want to use `fscanf` when operating on the file, not `scanf` (which reads from `stdin`)

Comment: I've tried stuff like scanf("T%s9") as an example: Example data would be like: T(20,100( (55,34) (40, 60) I'm only specifically looking for triangles.

Comment: That already deviates from the format you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Well no, I just placed num1-6 there as an example. I really meant it in the way I have it in the comment I placed. Let me edit that.

Comment: What makes you believe that [Xlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlib) is parsing files with the `T(28,100) (23,35) (99,54)` syntax? AFAIK, it is completely false! Or please edit your question to give more references.

Comment: BTW, if you want to code a GUI application in C++ on Linux, better use [Qt](http://qt.io/) than the raw, very low level, Xlib.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use a combination of scanf and perhaps something like bitwise operators in python? That's what I figured how one could do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define completely the input syntax (e.g. in [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) form) of your program and use standard [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques, probably to build some kind of [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) in memory (which you would display later on demand). You probably want to read the input line by line, e.g. with [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) because you might want some readahead.

You need to use standard [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32463160/841108)) and probably build some kind of AST in memory; perhaps using code generators like [flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) (for lexing) and [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) (for parsing) should be worthwhile. Otherwise consider some hand written [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

[Xlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlib) is an extremely low level but complex library (and you'll need to follow explicitly complex conventions like [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html)). In C++ on Linux, better use [Qt](http://qt.io/) or maybe [libsdl](https://www.libsdl.org/), or [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/),  etc....

Notice that `scanf` is a C function, not a C++ one.